# Bundling or combining two separate apps (Mac OSX)

Tags: python, macos, reactjs, electron, packaging

I have made a desktop application which relies on a python backend and a "client" GUI application written in React with Electron. To use the application I have to first initiate the python backend from the command line and then launch the Electron app.

In an attempt to make the app available for download I have packaged the Electron and python apps as two separate .app files. I then have then written a short ActionScript file that launches both apps. However, this launches them as two very separate apps (complete with two icons in the dock), which have to be exited separately.

How do I handle the launching of two applications as one unified app with a built in backend and client "sub-apps"?

Comment: why on earth would you use actionscript???

Comment: Super simple to launch two apps, as well as the ability to "Save as Application Bundle". Didn't really work out the way I hoped though... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bundle your Python application inside the Electron application and initiate the Python script as a [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

In your main process you can run something like

```
require('child_process').spawn('python', pathToScript)
```

For a complete implementation you can checkout [electron-python-example on GitHub](https://github.com/fyears/electron-python-example).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this as soon as I have access to my machine!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!